# sql query swapping

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table named **tbl_course** nad the data is like

```
SID   name                DisplayOrder       course
 1    Apple                  1                 1
 2    Orange                 2                 1
 3    Banana                 4                 1
 4    Grape                  3                 1
 5    Orange                 2                 2
 6    Banana                 1                 2
```

In the web page it will show order by displayorder.

Now in the bo side i will showing this values in grid with order buttons to change order by admin .
[image]

When I click on down arrow automatically swap to next item.

Eg:If I click on 1st down arrow from below  image(Apple) so its will come to 2nd row and orange will come 1st row.

So i want to write sp for this with help of course.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you want or need an SP for this? This is all client side presentation layer stuff. No reason to hit the DB again.

Comment: Thank you for you answer.The admin will change the order

Comment: @JoeStefanelli I think maybe they are storing the display order for the presentation layer so all clients will get the same ordering

Comment: in the fe side dispalying order purpose admin will change order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `@clickedDown` and `@courseId` are two parameters passed to your stored procedure, all it needs to do is to run this update statement:

```
update tbl_course
set DisplayOrder = case DisplayOrder when @clickedDown then @clickedDown+1 else @clickedDown end
where course=@courseId and DisplayOrder in (@clickedDown, clickedDown+1)
```